# Momentum space representation and time dependency

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, fourier-transform

I'm currently struggling with understanding how to find the momentum-representation of a wave function and I could need some help with understanding this. I know from varying sources that the Fourier-transform is an important key of understanding and computing this.

I have one proposed way of finding the momentum representation and that involes "de Broglie's momentum–wavelength relation" where we can express $\vec{p}$ as $\hbar$$\vec{k}$. Let's study the given wave function:
$$\Psi(\vec{k}) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^\frac{3}{2}}\int d^3r e^{-i\vec{k}\vec{r}}\psi(\vec{r})$$

1. If I were to substitute $\vec{k}$ with $\frac{\vec{p}}{\hbar}$ (de Broglie relation), then we would get the following function:
   $$\Psi(\frac{\vec{p}}{\hbar}) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^\frac{3}{2}}\int d^3r e^{-i\frac{\vec{p}}{\hbar}\vec{r}}\psi(\vec{r})$$

   My thought is that I can now express the momentum representation of $\Psi(\vec{k})$ as $$\Phi(\vec{p}) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^\frac{3}{2}}\int d^3r e^{-i\frac{\vec{p}}{\hbar}\vec{r}}\psi(\vec{r})$$ where I have combined $\vec{p}$ with $\hbar$ as it now only depends on $\vec{p}$ with a factor of constant $\hbar^{-1}$

Are these assumptions that I've made correct, and if not, how can I instead think to make it correct?

2. If I would want to determine $\Psi(\vec{k},t)$ at a time $t > 0$, could I just plug in the term $\omega t$ into the exponential, like this:
   $$\Psi(\vec{k}) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^\frac{3}{2}}\int d^3r e^{-i(\vec{k}\vec{r}-\vec{\omega}t)}\psi(\vec{r}))$$
   Same question here, are my assumptions correct, and if not, how can I think differently to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first point, you are basically right, the only trouble being the normalisation. Here, assuming the position-space wavefunction is normalized :
$$\int \text d^3\vec x |\psi(\vec x)|^2 = 1$$
we know that its Fourier transform (with the convention used in OP) is normalized as well :
$$\int \text d^3 \vec k|\Psi(\vec k)|^2 = 1$$
Then, to give a normalized momentum-space wavefunction $\Phi(\vec p)$, we need an extra factor of $\hbar^{-3/2}$ :
\begin{align}
\Phi(\vec p) &= \frac{1}{\hbar^{3/2}}\Psi(\vec p/\hbar) \\
&= \frac{1}{(2\pi\hbar)^{3/2}}\int\text d^3 x  e^{-i \vec p\cdot\vec x/\hbar }\psi(\vec x)
\end{align}

For the second point, the relation between the position-space wavefunction and the momentum-space wavefunction *at the same time $t$* is always the same :

$$\Phi(\vec p,t)= \frac{1}{(2\pi\hbar)^{3/2}}\int\text d^3 x  e^{-i \vec p\cdot\vec x/\hbar }\psi(\vec x,t)$$
ie we only take the *spatial* Fourier transform.

Up to this moment, we were only dealing with *kinematics*. To relate the wave-functions at different times, we need to specify the *dynamics* of the system, which is done by choosing a Hamiltonian operator. For a free non-relativistic particle, whose Hamiltonian is $H = -\frac{\hbar ^2 }{2m} \nabla^2$, we see that the Schrödinger equation implies that the momentum-space wavefunction satisfies :
$$i\hbar \partial_t\Phi(\vec p,t) = \frac{p^2}{2m}\Phi(\vec p,t)$$
This is solved by :
$$\Phi(\vec p,t) = e^{-iE_p t/\hbar} \Phi(\vec p,0)$$
with $E_p = \hbar \omega_p = \frac{p^2}{2m}$. Plugging back in the definition of $\Phi(\vec p,0)$, we obtain :
$$\Phi(\vec p,t ) = \frac{1}{(2\pi\hbar)^{3/2}} \int \text dx e^{i(\vec p \cdot \vec x - E_p t)/\hbar} \psi(\vec x,0)$$